# Wrap a pivot transformation in subquery and alias it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a work around for a client which requires I do a rows to columns pivot transformation in SQL then access this data via a subquery.

We have a CTE based solution that we thought would work, however we must insert this query into a shell query to use it with our system's UI and the CTE solution is not workable.

However, we know that if we could access the pivot transformed data via a nested subquery that should work.

Below is a working example of the PIVOT transformation and attempt at code for the subquery/aliasing solution we are hoping is possible to use in later joins.

```
-- create the test data

create table #testData
(
    PK int, 
    DayID DateTime, 
    ReferenceCategorical VarChar(50),
    Value numeric
)

Insert Into #testData(PK, DayID, ReferenceCategorical, Value) VALUES (1,  
'2017-10-1', 'Red', 1516)
Insert Into #testData(PK, DayID, ReferenceCategorical, Value)VALUES (2,          
'2017-10-1', 'Blue', 1776)
Insert Into #testData(PK, DayID, ReferenceCategorical, Value)VALUES (3,      
'2017-10-1','Green', 1733)
Insert Into #testData(PK, DayID, ReferenceCategorical, Value)VALUES (4,  
'2017-10-2', 'Red', 1439)
Insert Into #testData(PK, DayID, ReferenceCategorical, Value)VALUES (5,  
'2017-10-2', 'Blue', 1882)
Insert Into #testData(PK, DayID, ReferenceCategorical, Value)VALUES (6,  
'2017-10-2', 'Green', 1372)

-- the rows to columns tranformation 

select DayID, [Red] ,[Blue], [Green]
FROM (select * from #testData) og       
PIVOT(  
max(Value)  
FOR  ReferenceCategorical in ([Red] ,[Blue], [Green] )
) pvt
```

This attempted code doesn't work but should display what we are trying to do.

```
select * from 
( select DayID, [Red] ,[Blue], [Green]
FROM (select DayID, ReferenceCategorical, Value from #testData) og       
PIVOT(  
max(Value)  
FOR  ReferenceCategorical in ([Red] ,[Blue], [Green] )
) pvt)
```

Answer (score 1):

It just needs an alias like `AS T`

```
select * from 
( select DayID, [Red] ,[Blue], [Green]
FROM (select DayID, ReferenceCategorical, Value from #testData) og       
PIVOT(  
max(Value)  
FOR  ReferenceCategorical in ([Red] ,[Blue], [Green] )
) pvt) AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to alias the entire query. Here is an example showing how you would join the sub-query back to testData, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT #testData.dayID as main_query, sub.*
FROM #testData
INNER JOIN
(select DayID, [Red] ,[Blue], [Green]
FROM (select * from #testData) og       
PIVOT(  
max(Value)  
FOR  ReferenceCategorical in ([Red] ,[Blue], [Green] )
) pvt) sub
ON #testData.dayID = sub.dayID
```

Available here: http://rextester.com/RCW4104